# How to give a value to long code for repeating it on various occassions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a long code which I want to use on multiple random pages of my website. Copying and pasting it everywhere is a tough job for me. So, I want to assign a value to it using javascript. If I use that value, entire code should be executed. I tried to use `document.getElementById` and tried to insert the entire code in `innerHTML` which didn't work out. Here's the code which I want to assign the value for.

```html
<style>
  .container {
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: xx-small;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #e6e7ee;
    box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 10px #a3a3a3, inset -5px -5px 10px #dddddd;
  }
  
  img {
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #a3a3a3, -5px -5px 10px #dddddd;
    border: 1px solid silver;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <img border="0" align="left" data-original-height="884" data-original-width="800" height="40px" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GbF0Uslf3Uo/XyEjbgr6hCI/AAAAAAAADFg/dziRURov-J0QMftcWgx5N_lEpIP7jjMGgCPcBGAYYCw/s320/Screenshot_2020-07-25-23-27-02-1.png" width="40px" /> 
  - Becky Lynch<br />
  - Wrestler<br />
  - WWE
</div>
```

If I type `<div id="becky"></div>` on any page, The above code should be executed. Is there any option available?

Comment: To include common static content on multiple pages use server side includes. JS is not a good solution for this problem. Also note that the CSS should be stored in a separate stylesheet which can be cached. Don't add that to the content each time you include it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp